Connections between Stokes' Theorem, information theory, and the definition of life/Intelligence
Stokes' theorem is a well-known result in mathematics. It generalizes the idea that the total "flow" of something across a surface's boundary can be related to what's happening inside the surface.
This is probably far-fetched, but could there be a connection between this and concepts in information theory, or even the definition of life/intelligence?
Like, information flowing inside the surface corresponds to perception. Information change within the surface is reasoning/computation. Information flowing outwards is action on the environment. Can one define life, intelligence or individuality in terms of these three (or similar) quantities? In this analogy, Stokes' theorem would say something like:
Action - Perception = Reasoning
I was reading this very interesting Aeon article today. While it's obviously not about Stokes' theorem, it made me wonder if Stokes-like concepts or intuitions could have a place in understanding these kinds of ideas.

No, one cannot define life, intelligence or individuality in such simplistic terms. Otherwise, Boolean circuits, black holes, and even rocks and walls, among other things, would be live intelligent individuals, see Godfrey-Smith, Triviality Arguments Against Functionalism. Information "flowing in", "transforming" and "flowing out" is a very generic occurrence.

We have zero information about which parts of the universe experience consciousness (other than humans and probably many animals). I claim there is no more reason to assume that a rock cannot experience consciousness than to assume it can.

From an information-theory perspective, you don't have more information than a puddle of mud.  Finding out that the you-stuff is in so-and-so configuration provides just as much information as finding out that the puddle-stuff is in so-and-so configuration.  It's a theory of probability propagation from one state to the next, rather than a theory of perception or knowledge.

Is the universes function of recycling energy a definition of life. Metabolism creates work as it recycles energy. Metabolism happens in all life. If it happens in the universe, is the universe not the same, depending on the validity of my definition of life.

"Did you go inside the Sphere?"

"you don't have more information than a puddle of mud" Totally disagree. A substantial continuity of patterns will persist through perturbations (that don't kill) acting on a living being, whereas the mud will be very predictably changed by perturbations. Our genes contain around 3.1 Gb, which can be regarded as accumulated information about surviving & reproducing in our niche. Mud does not.

Are you downvoting all the replies?

Perhaps the towering Stoke's and Green's theorem in an arbitrary space with Cartan algebra of exterior differential forms in intrinsic differential geometry as the relation between a universal covering and its base space yields a primordial template for information-theoretic intelligence...

HOW IN GOD'S NAME DID YOU DERIVE THE EQUATION ACTION - PERCEPTION = REASONING?!

How about outputs - inputs = (Integral of) computation

The line integral of a vector field along a closed loop equals the integral of its curl ("rot") over the surface enclosed by the loop. See Stokes' theorem for an introduction and the precise mathematical formula.
The first step to elaborate on your thoughts is to translate your key concepts

perception,
action,
reasoning

into the mathematical terms from Stokes’ theorem.
IMO your post does not give any clue how to do this. Your analogy lacks any reasoning for your proposal “Action - Perception = Reasoning”.

This is not right. "The flow of a vector field through the surface of a volume equals the rotation of the vector field integrated over the interior of the volume."
For a compact surface with boundary surrounding a 3-dimensional region:
Rather, the flux of the vector field through the surface equals the integral of the divergence of the vector field integrated over the volume bounded by the surface.

@Daniel Asimov You are right, I corrected my statement. Thanks.

D.Halsey You are right, I mean rot F = Nabla x F, the rotation of the vector field F.

I like the term 'teleonomic matter' used by David Krakauer, Professor of Complex Systems at the Santa Fe Institute, who uses it to define the domaim of complex systems: teleonomic systems get information about their environment, record it, and change their dynamics in some way as a result. It's easy to see all evolutionary algorithms as belonging in this domain, & so memetics. Teleonomic matter also gives a ground-up way to define what an observer is in quantum mechanics: it's about the transmission of information with 'aboutness', that constrains future outcomes of a patch of the world, to a location that persists as a 'subject', ie an engine or an organism, or any system under consideration. In this way we can identify a common trait in systems that become more complex, this hallmark of feedback loops. Intelligence though is just one set of patterns, in the domain of evolutionary algorithms, which are just a subset in the vast domain of complex systems. (paragraph from this answer: Can evolutionary processes be characterized as a form of intelligence?)
Shannon defined information in signal transmission, as the inverse of entropy. There's also the speculated but not proven law of Conservation of Information, also called the No-Hiding theorem. The Critical Brain hypothesis suggests the brain is a non-linear system, held close to criticality between phase transitions.
So assembling those. Complex systems have an 'inside' that interacts with the 'outside' (NB also Strange Loops). Information seems to conserved (Maxwell's Demon seems to give a clear link of thermodynamics and information generally, not just thermodynamic). Stokes theory can't deal with fractal surfaces like the Koch Snowflake, though real surfaces can only approximate true fractals - although Turbulent black holes grow fractal skins as they feed suggests Planck-scale resolution is possible. What if we can think about minds as the kinds of strange loop that through net-increase in entropy, are able to focus their decision tree in a non-linear self referencing way, and we could expect the information change to be fractal in some way?
Time crystals and the Holographic Principle also come to mind. Maybe AdS-CFT correspondence, and a link between infinite-dimensional Hilbert space (bulk) and finite spacetime (surface).
There is eneough I'd say to make it an interesting area to consider.

Stokes theorem takes its most elegant form in the theory of manifolds where it says the integral of a differential form over a boundary is equal to the integral of the exterior derivative of the differential form over the volume. It's also seen as a generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus which relates integrals to derivatives. You say:

This is probably far-fetched, but could there be a connection between this and concepts in information theory, or even the definition of life/intelligence

Personally, I think life cannot be reduced to computation. This is not the view of the Aeon article you linked to. Its an assumption they make not a truth they have uncovered.
A cell has a boundary but that does not mean that Stokes theorem is useful here.
